# Trouble defining multi_index_container ordered_non_unique

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I'm playing around with some boost containers, but I recently came a blockade as I can't seem to define multi_index_container correctly. I'm following an example i grabbed offline but it still gives me and error message:

```
struct boost::multi_index::global_fun<const node&, int, <error-constant>>

Error: Expression must have a constant value
```

Here is my declaration:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <boost/config.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key_extractors.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/global_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct node
{
    node(std::string da, int in) {
        data = da;
        numerical = in;
    };
    std::string data;
    int numerical;
};

int main()
{
    typedef multi_index_container<
        node,
        indexed_by<
            hashed_unique<
                member<node,std::string, &node::data>>,
            ordered_non_unique<
                global_fun<const node&, int, node::numerical>> //right here, the value numerical errors
            >
        > node_type;



}
```

I have a hunch that I'm not including a file for this, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: `node::numerical` is obviously not a global function but a member. Wht are you trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  node,
  indexed_by<  hashed_unique< member<node,std::string, &node::data> >
             , ordered_non_unique< member<node, int, &node::numerical> >
            >
  > node_type;
```

`global_fun` expects, well, a gloabl function. `&node::numerical` is a member just like `&node::data`. You can of course write a function that accepts a node and extracts it, but why would you?

You are also missing the `member.hpp` include.

Comment: Ohhh, I see now. My brilliant mind thought legs was a member of their struct, and tried to call my member. Appreciate the help!